# If a curve is not smooth at a given interval, how can you find the length of that curve at that interval?

Tags: parametrization

I'm wondering if you could somehow calculate the length of the curve even if it is not smooth at a given interval.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! You may want to specify what kind of curves you are considering. For example, if curve means *continuous map $[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R^n$*, you may for example consider piecewise linear curves, whose length can be specified by adding up the lengths of the line segments. Those are not smooth in general...

Comment: If my curve makes a sharp turn(x'(t) and y'(t) is 0) at one of the endpoints, say "a"(from [a,b]), does that method still apply?

Comment: What I was trying to say is: There are many different definitions of curves, most of them coming with their own definition of length. The curve-integral of cause only applies to smooth/$C^1$-curves. So unless you give more context by editing your post to specify what type of curves you are considering (a smooth curve cannot have non-smooth points) I am afraid your question won’t get a satisfying answer. Besides, how can a curve make a turn *in an endpoint*?

Comment: I purposefully didn't give context because I do not want to violate academic rules our school enforces. However, you did answer my question accidentally! Your point  does make sense: "how can a curve make a sharp turn at an endpoint?" Thank you very much!